# Need to return a value when XML Load event is triggered actionscript

Tags: actionscript, event-handling

Actionscript is really stressing me out! My code is too messy to post as I have tried everything from design patterns to  procedural approaches. In short, is there any way i can retrieve my XML data in a variable after loading the URL request?

```
        var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
        this.loader = new URLLoader(req);
        this.loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, readXML);
```

Basically I am trying to capture my XML output so I can place it a list. There doesn't seem to be a way to assign it to a variable without it losing scope when the event is over.

Answer (score 0):

in your function readXML you can write the xml into a var

> private var xml:XML;
>
> private function readXML(e:Event):void{
>
> ```
>  xml = new XML(e.target.data);
>  trace (xml.toXMLString());
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be able to be assigned to a variable outside of the event handling. So I have to do all the work in a messy pile of code and it makes OO programming seem less intuitive.

Comment: this ist just because the var was defined in inside the function if you define it outside it surly is valid outside too. My mistake, it should be xml =..... and the var definetion ust be outside of the function.